# multicols environment stretches content

Tags: graphics, floats, multicol

I'm using the multicols package to place a graphic next to a description:

```
\subsubsection{Geometrische Darstellung}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Für $z = (a + ib)$:
\begin{itemize}
\item $|z| = r = |\vec v| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
\item $\varphi = \arg(z)$
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{res/Grafik-Darstellung-KomplexeZahlen/Grafik-Darstellung-KomplexeZahlen}
\caption{Darstellung einer Komplexen Zahl}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
```

But multicols stretches the text content (itemize) to be as height as the image in the right column:
[image: muticols stretches text paragraph]

How can I prevent multicols from doing this? I'd also be open to a better method for placing the text next to the graphic.

Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to place some text besides the image, you can use a couple of `minipage` environments.

If you want the whole document text to wrap around the image, a different solution would be in order (`\wrapfloat` for example).

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Geometrische Darstellung}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        Für $z = (a + ib)$:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $|z| = r = |\vec v| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
        \item $\varphi = \arg(z)$
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{Darstellung einer Komplexen Zahl}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly a surrounding `minipage` instead of `figure` and `\captionof`.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't that require package `capt-of`? What would be the difference instead of the `figure`?

Comment: It wouldn't float.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I'll keep the `minipage`-environment in mind, it seems very useful ;)