# How to stop multicol from spreading the contents of a column?

Tags: pdftex, multicol

(Yes, I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287937/multicols-environment-stretches-content), but it only fixes the problem by not using multicol in a situation where it isn't even needed)

So, my problem with multicol is that it stretches the content inside its environment. How do I get around this?

Example code:

```latex
\documentclass[
12pt,                        % Font size
a4paper                      % Paper type
]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[
margin=2.7cm,                % Margin size
marginparwidth=2cm,          % Margin note size
marginparsep=3mm             % Space between margin and text
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % UTF-8 support
\usepackage{multicol}        % Spread text on multiple columns
\usepackage{blindtext}       % Filler text

% Basic document info
\title{Testing multicol}
\date{}   % Show no date in the title
\author{} % Empty author to not get a warn about missing author

\begin{document}
\maketitle % Show the title

\begin{multicols*}{2}
 Example text

 some text

 text

 more text

 \columnbreak

 \blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

How it looks like:
[image]

Comment: You can use `\par\vfill\null` before `\columnbreak`.

Comment: @Skillmon see also https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/682

Comment: See also `\vspace*{\fill}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\vfill` to add a glue which will fill the page vertically with infinite stretchability, this way the other stretches added between paragraphs are overruled by it. To prevent the `\vfill` from being removed you need to add something after it, which is what `\null` does (that is "put an empty box here").

If you want this behaviour for every column, not only where you explicitly do `\columnbreak` you can use `\raggedcolumns` instead.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,                        % Font size
a4paper                      % Paper type
]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[
margin=2.7cm,                % Margin size
marginparwidth=2cm,          % Margin note size
marginparsep=3mm             % Space between margin and text
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % UTF-8 support
\usepackage{multicol}        % Spread text on multiple columns
\usepackage{blindtext}       % Filler text

% Basic document info
\title{Testing multicol}
\date{}   % Show no date in the title
\author{} % Empty author to not get a warn about missing author

\begin{document}
\maketitle % Show the title

\begin{multicols*}{2}
 Example text

 some text

 text

 more text

 \vfill
 \null
 \columnbreak

 \blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[
12pt,                        % Font size
a4paper                      % Paper type
]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[
margin=2.7cm,                % Margin size
marginparwidth=2cm,          % Margin note size
marginparsep=3mm             % Space between margin and text
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % UTF-8 support
\usepackage{multicol}        % Spread text on multiple columns
%\raggedcolumns              % use ragged columns globally
\usepackage{blindtext}       % Filler text

% Basic document info
\title{Testing multicol}
\date{}   % Show no date in the title
\author{} % Empty author to not get a warn about missing author

\begin{document}
\maketitle % Show the title

\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \raggedcolumns % use ragged columns locally in this environment
 Example text

 some text

 text

 more text

 \columnbreak

 \blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Both result in:

[image]